# Is it safe to assume that python interpreter is installed on Debian/Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, python

Do servers get python as one of basic system packages? Can Debian or Ubuntu live without working python interpreter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ubuntu-minimal depend on python.  Therefore you can count on python being installed on Ubuntu.

Debian shows python-minimal tagged as system boot. Therefore you should be able to count on python on Debian as well.  As noted by others, a minimal Debian installation does not include python.

Comment: In Debian, it's not marked as *essential*, so it's closer to "most likely" then "for certain".

Comment: Indeed. While my systems typically install python from other dependencies, and I like to have it for my own projects, when I install Debian I don't install anything but the bare install, which does not include python.